# Using VB to allow the user to pick a folder which loads all of the files into a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Struggling with the above question.

I have code which can load all of the files from a folder into a spreadsheet. I need to make it so the user can pick a folder rather than the path already being defined in the code.

Below is the code I already have, any guidance will be appreciated.

```
Sub From_IDPXML_To_ExcelReport()

On Error GoTo errh
Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim myPath

myPath = "File path here” 
Dim myFile
myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xml") 

Dim t As Long, N As Long, row As Long, column As Long
t = 2
N = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Do While myFile <> ""
N = N + 1
Set WB = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
If N > 1 Then
row = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
column = WB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).column
WB.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(3, "A"), Cells(row, column)).Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(t, "A")
Else
WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(t, "A")
End If
WB.Close False
t = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row + 1
myFile = Dir()
Loop    

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

myWB.Save
Exit Sub
errh:
MsgBox "no xml files in folder specified" 
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: So your question is about how to allow the user to select a directory? If so, did you consider searching for prior questions here first, before posting? I find several results by searching for `[vba] select directory` which seem like they'd meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure,  replace:

```
myPath = "File path here”
```

with:

```
myPath = GetFolder()
```

and include this **UDF** in you module:

```
Public Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem & "\"
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most simple code to have user select a directory is:

```
Sub dir_browser()
   Set dir_chooser = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

   dir_chooser.Show

   picked_dir = dir_chooser.SelectedItems(1)

End Sub
```